# TableLayout, Different Button actions depending on data in TableRow

Tags: android

I have the following problem:

I have a TableLayout along with several TableRows, which are dynamically created.
On the right side of every row I create a button, which should call another activity.
Now I want to pass some information with `intent.putExtra()`. In this case I want so pass the row number, which is also the first information in the row.
Here is a picture of the current state:

[image: It is within a scroll view, s]

This is how I create the buttons during run-time (in a loop):

```
Button b1 = new Button (this, null, android.R.attr.buttonStyleSmall);
            b1.setId(1000+grButtonId);
            b1.setText("Request GR");
            b1.setLayoutParams(params);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {    
                                    // Some code, taken out for clarity
                                    // See next code snippet  
                }
            });
grButtonId++;
tr.addView(b1);
```

My idea so far is to use the id of the button (of course), and get the line number by the value of `grButtonId`.

Now comes my problem, let's have a detailed look at my `onClick`method:

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {    
// finished is true, as soon as GRRequest has recieved the data
if(!finished & !dataRequested){
  new GRRequest().execute(getIntent().getLongExtra("poNr", 0),(long)view.getId());
  b1.setText("Show GR");
  Log.d("DataList", detailList.toString());
  dataRequested=true;
 }
else{
  if (dataRequested){
   b1.setText("Show GR");   
  }
Intent intent = new Intent(DataTableCreater.this, GRTableCreater.class);
                    intent.putExtra("lineNr",view.getId());
                    intent.putExtra("dataList", detailList);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
              }
```

When I request my data, the button I clicked on gets set to "Show GR" , as intended. The other buttons stay on "Request GR", this is also fine. But now I want these Buttons to Change to "Show GR" when tapped first and on second tap start the activity. 
By now, the buttons change to "Show GR" and directly start the activity.
What would be a solution, to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean Array `clickedOnce[] = new boolean[grButtonId+1]` one field for every Button.
Then have this

```
    public void onClick(View view) {    

    if(!finished){
    new GRRequest().execute(getIntent().getLongExtra("poNr", 0),(long)view.getId());
    b1.setText("Show GR");
    Log.d("DataList", detailList.toString());
    clickedOnce[Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(view.getId()).substring(1,4))]=true; //sets the clickedOnce for this button to true, substring(1,4) is needed to cancle the leading 1 from the id  
                    }
                    else{
                    //Checks, if the button was clicked once        
                    if (!clickedOnce[Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(view.getId()).substring(1,4))]){
                    b1.setText("Show GR");  
                    clickedOnce[Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(view.getId()).substring(1,4))]=true;
                    }
                    else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DataTableCreater.this, GRTableCreater.class);
                    intent.putExtra("lineNr",view.getId());
                    intent.putExtra("dataList", detailList);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
              }
```